# How to make a custom class Codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm using a thread safe dictionary found on [Github](https://github.com/geekaurora/ThreadSafeDictionary)

But how to make the `ThreadSafeDictionary` in that repo conform to the `Codable`?

It seems initialise a new lock in the encoder function would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a subclass of `ThreadSafeDictionary` which works with Codable `Key` and `Value` types. In my opinion it's best to pretend that we are dealing with a simple dictionary, so lets use a `singleValueContainer`.

```swift
class CodableThreadSafeDictionary<Key: Codable & Hashable, Value: Codable>: ThreadSafeDictionary<Key, Value>, Codable {

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dictionary = try container.decode(DictionaryType.self)
        protectedCache = CZMutexLock(dictionary)
    }

    public required init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, Value)...) {
        var dictionary = DictionaryType()
        for (key, value) in elements {
            dictionary[key] = value
        }
        protectedCache = CZMutexLock(dictionary)
        super.init()
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        var dictionary = DictionaryType()
        protectedCache.readLock {
            dictionary = $0
        }
        try container.encode(dictionary)
    }

}
```

But because of the fact that the `protectedCache` is a `fileprivate` property, you will need to put this implementation in the same file

##### Note!

You could consider limiting `Key` to just a `String` for a better compatibility with JSON format:

```swift
CodableThreadSafeDictionary<Key: String, Value: Codable>
```

Comment: Please consider that the *keys* in a `Codable` context are required to be String. `Codable & Hashable` is too broad.

Comment: But are they required? It looks like the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5563) of `Decodable` and `Encodable` extensions for `Dictionary` support not only `String` keys. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, actually `Int`s are supported, too. But the two currently available formats JSON and Property List require String keys.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this information